# WordPress woocommerce_get_country_locale hook not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am trying to use the filter `woocommerce_get_country_locale` to remove the "State" field for a specific country. However, it does not work.

Here is what I tried:

**Attempt 1**

```php
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_get_country_locale',
    static function (array $locale): array {
        $locale['HK']['state']['hidden'] = true;
        return $locale;
    }
);
```

**Attempt2**

```php
apply_filters(
    'woocommerce_get_country_locale',
    [
        'HK' => [
            'postcode' => [
                'required' => false,
            ],
            'city' => [
                'label' => __('Town / District', 'woocommerce'),
                // 'placeholder' => __( 'Town / District', 'woocommerce' )
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

Please suggest how to achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-remove-fields-on-edit-address looks like it might have what you want - Rolf Hassel's answer

Comment: did 'state'=>array('hidden' =>true) do anything when added to your filter?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding to your array:

```
        'state' => array(
           'required' => false
         )
```

Like France in the function, for example.

So your filter would look like

```
    apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_country_locale', array(
               'HK' => array(
                'postcode' => array(
                  'required' => false
                ),
                'city'  => array(
                'label'       => __( 'Town / District', 'woocommerce' ),
                //'placeholder' => __( 'Town / District', 'woocommerce' )
                )
                'state' => array(
                  'required' => false
                )
            )
        ));
```

The function which controls this lives in

`woocommerce/includes/class-wc-countries.php`

It could be removed there but you would need to take great care to ensure that this is maintained when you update WooCommerce. I would not recommend editing core theme files in this way but it can produce the desired result.

This might help in providing good background to the get country locale function:
http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_countriesget_country_locale/?bwscid1=2

And this might provide another way - showing that that country is not allowed if you wanted to remove HK altogether:
http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_countriesget_allowed_countries/

Something in the answers here might help to point you in a more correct way to do it:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73062/how-to-force-wordpress-to-temporarily-switch-locale-using-qtranslate

This also might explain some of the behaviour: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120741/cant-change-a-label-in-woocommerce-with-the-normal-filter

Comment: off-course I didn't edit core file, I just overwrite, now when adding this `'state' => array(
                  'required' => false
                )` , is state removed?

Comment: I think when we give required , then its make `required` field, but I need to remove the state field for particular country!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know and can't test here - As France doesn't have states as such I assumed it would remove it - does  'state' => array(
           ''         ) work? You could edit core file experimentally -  or as a last resort.

Comment: Last answer on this page seems to explain the problem with state fields ialocin's answer might help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120741/cant-change-a-label-in-woocommerce-with-the-normal-filter   says: code isn't working for all cases, because on country selection the state field of the checkout form gets updated via javascript. To make it work it's necessary to add the desired name for those cases as translation, using the...  and provides a suggestion

Comment: 'state' => array(
           'hidden' => true
         )                                                                                                                         may be a silly idea and please let me know if it is no good so I can delete it!

Comment: thanks for your efforts! i am not sure if we use `'state'=>array('hidden' =>true)` it affects the other `country state field` showing

Comment: If it works at all it should only apply to HK - have you tried sending it `'placeholder`   'placeholder' => __( '', '' )` (two x pairs of single inverted commas) - or using the `unset()` method from the website info?

Comment: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/7729 covers a similar issue and uses  $locales[$country]['state']['placeholder'] = "";
Note the plural  's' on `$locales[`  might that work in your existing code where there is no 's'?  possibly could be put as 'state' => array('placeholder >= "") 'placeholder' => ""

Comment: many thanks for your efforts but `'state'=>array('placehoder' => '')` not helping me

Comment: $locales['HK']['state']['hidden'] = true;  made no difference? (with the extra "s")  What happens if you remove state from core files? Does it just give you a default?

Comment: Could you hide it with css? Using style="display: none;"  If that worked and hid them all the something could be worked out to apply just to the HK one.